# Stored Procedure vs SQL Statement in SSIS Execute SQL Task and a Full Result Set

Tags: ssis

In the SSIS Execute SQL task, when I use a stored procedure to return data to a full result set, the resulting C# DataTable object only contains one row/column, with all values contained within one row/column.  The rows are separated by commas, columns by dashes.  However, when the same code executes via the SQL Statement, I get multiple rows/columns, so I can access via row[0].toString() etc.

This behavior occurs with both ADO.NET and OLEDB connections.  Is this by design?

This link started me in the initial direction, but haven't found a definitive answer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/result-sets-in-the-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014

Comment: I've never seen that happen.   You're probably doing something the wrong way.

Comment: Please provide a sample query and perhaps a screenshot of how you have the Execute SQL Task configured. I too have never seen this before and I've seen quite a bit of SSIS ;)

Comment: @TabAlleman.  You were right.  I was doing something the wrong way.  I forgot to change the stored procedure I was calling to the new version that had columns and rows. (ARGH!!!!!) Not sure if it's worth adding that in as an answer. Maybe it will help someone else.